# How to efficiently identify sequential changes across multiple columns in a data table?

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, sequence

I have a very large data table with the following columns. Where pos1 and pos2 give aligned sequences across the different categories cat1 and cat2.

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)

x <- 1:60
y <- 100:41

dt <- data.table(cat1 = c(rep("A", 40), rep("B", 60)),
                 cat2 = c(rep("A", 75), rep("C", 25)),
                 pos1 = c(x[-sample(x, 10)], x[-sample(x, 10)]),
                 pos2 = c(x[-sample(x, 10)], y[-sample(x, 10)])
```

I need to create a grouping column where the id changes when one of either cat1 or cat2 changes, or the difference between pos1 or pos2 is greater than 1.

I have tried as follows:

```
dt$grp <- as.numeric(paste0(rleid(c(0,cumsum(as.numeric(with(dt, cat1[1:(length(cat1)-1)] != cat1[2:length(cat1)]))))),
                                  rleid(c(0,cumsum(as.numeric(with(dt, cat2[1:(length(cat2)-1)] != cat2[2:length(cat2)]))))),
                                  rleid(c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(dt$pos1)) > 1))),
                                  rleid(c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(dt$pos2)) > 1))) ))
```

However, this method is slow and produces some errors in my dataset. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this can be improved?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `data.table` package I would do something like the following.

```
dt[,`:=`(pos1id=rleid(cumsum(abs(diff(c(0,pos1)))>1)),
         pos2id=rleid(cumsum(abs(diff(c(0,pos2)))>1)),
         cat1id=rleid(cat1),
         cat2id=rleid(cat2))][
   , `:=`(grp=.GRP), by = c("pos1id","pos2id",
                            "cat1id","cat2id")         
         ]
```

The `:=` operator modifies the data in place which is typically fast. Additionally, you do not need to do all these operations in one go, you can make several columns and then index them based on the internal `.GRP` parameter for data.table.